# День недели по дате в python

Tags: python, функции, формулы

Нужно найти день недели по дате, но такая формула не работает:

```
(d + float(2.6 * m - 0.2) - 2 * c + y + float(y/4) + float(c/4))
```

получается отрицательное число... Как правильно?

Comment: что такое с в вашей формуле?

Comment: А обязательно через эту формулу? Такое условие? В плане, есть [много других вариантов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date), как можно найти день недели по дате, может, они Вам подойдут?

Comment: Во-первых вы потеряли из формулы остаток от деления на 7, а во-вторых там самое главное что означают эти буквы: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Disparate_variation

Comment: И нужно приводить всегда исходные данные, для которых вы хотите получить какой-то результат, что мы должны подставить в формулу, чтобы воспроизвести ваш результат, какие значения?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

День недели по дате в пайтоне лучше всего искать с помощью модуля [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime

>>> now = datetime.now()      # текущие дата и время
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 23, 14, 46, 19, 60107)

>>> datetime.weekday(now)     # день недели в виде числа, понедельник - 0, воскресенье - 6
1

>>> datetime.isoweekday(now)  # день недели в виде числа, понедельник - 1, воскресенье - 7
2
```