# Вывод сегодняшнего дня недели из ручного списка слов с помощью python datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, дата, datetime

Как в Python сделать вывод сегодняшнего дня недели из названий кастомного списка?
Чтоб

```
from datetime import date
WeekdayNowEng = date.today().strftime("%A")
```

возвращал текущий день недели из списка:

```
weekday_name = ['Понедельника', 'Вторника', 'Среды', 'Четверга', 'Пятницы', 'Субботы', 'Воскресенья']
```

Есть похожий [ответ на названия месяцев или номер дня прописью тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/623782/550515), интересует подобное для дня недели

Comment: `weekday_name[date.today().weekday()]`

Comment: ближайший по смыслу [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1247680/178576)

Comment: спасибо, за ответ @aleksandrbarakin

Answer (score 0):

Нашел временное решение через `if`:

```
if WeekdayNowEng == "Monday":
    WeekdayNowRu = "Понедельника"
if WeekdayNowEng == "Tuesday":
    WeekdayNowRu = "Вторника"
if WeekdayNowEng == "Wednesday":
    WeekdayNowRu = "Среды"
if WeekdayNowEng == "Thursday":
    WeekdayNowRu = "Четверга"
if WeekdayNowEng == "Friday":
    WeekdayNowRu  = "Пятницы"   
if WeekdayNowEng == "Saturday":
    WeekdayNowRu = "Субботы"
if WeekdayNowEng == "Sunday":
    WeekdayNowRu = "Воскресенья"
```

Comment: Вы читали комментарии под вопросом? В первом же комментарии дается очень простое и компактное решение.

Comment: @insolor спасибо, уже увидел, ответил до того, как обновил страницу